# Touches turn on and off light

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to set alpha of a `SKNode` every time it is clicked either to 0 or 1. My code currently turns it off but won't turn it back on. Any idea why?

```
- (void)handleTouchedPoint:(CGPoint)touchedPoint {
    touchedNode = [self nodeAtPoint:touchedPoint];

    // Detects which node was touched by utilizing names.
    if ([touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"play"]) {
        isOnPlay = true;
        NSLog(@"Touched play");
    }
    if ([touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"light1"]) {
        //NSLog(@"%.2f", touchedNode.alpha);
        if(touchedNode.alpha != 0.0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Off");
            touchedNode.alpha = 0.0;
            //[touchedNode setAlpha:0.0];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"On");
            touchedNode.alpha = 1.0;
            //[touchedNode setAlpha:1.0];
        }
        NSLog(@"Touched light");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you tried to turn it back on, did "Touched light" get printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be running into the famous float rounding issue. Use debug and check the values. The alpha might not be exactly zero.

Comment: This can't be it. 0 and 1 can be represented exactly. Since the code only sets it to 0 or 1 it can't be anything else.

Comment: ok so my comparison fails it keeps going into 0.0 so this might be the problem? any fixes?

Comment: I printed it out it actually ended up being 0.000000015

Comment: @AngatvirSanghera How did you fix it? How was it getting that tiny, non-zero value to begin with?

Comment: yes i just changed the comparison to >= .5 then i set it to 0

Comment: If i remember correctly, float rounding issues will also be different between 32 and 64bit implementations.

Comment: The mystery to me is how `alpha` is getting a value like `0.000000015`. `0` and `1` are exact values. There can't be round-off issues with `0` and `1`.